# Can you specify an orm.xml without a supporting persistence.xml?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

I'm very new to Spring and JPA so I'll try a different approach to ask this question:

Given that there is a persistence.xml and persistence unit defined in separate jar (call it "core.jar").

In the project/app that I am developing, which includes core.jar, can I override the annotations in the entities contained in core.jar with an orm.xml specified in my project's META-INF folder?

Based on my experiments, it would appear that just specifying an orm.xml in my project isn't enough since I can purposefully insert syntax errors into the orm.xml file and the application starts up.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: In JPA the answer is no, persistence.xml is obligatory. With Spring no idea, but it does bastardise some of the ideas of JPA

Comment: Thanks Neil, I'm going to try playing with the <import resource=> tag.